# "u8" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am working on the communication between a raspberry pi and a kestrel plate (from procerus technologies). Now, I need to receive information from the packages of the kestrel, for this I am using an old code used in a Gumstix. At the time of compiling it gives me the error of the title ("u8" was not declared in this scope). The error is present in several files. For example

I suppose the error is related to the Linux version

```cpp
#include "dllsetup.h"
#include "type.h"
#include <vector>
#include <linux/types.h> 
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifndef LINUX
    EXTERN_LINK template class DYNAMIC_LINK std::vector<u8>;
#endif

//! Packet Data Type defines for easy writing of code.

typedef std::vector<u8> PacketData;
typedef std::vector<u8>::iterator PacketDataIter;
```

Comment: What is `u8` supposed to be? To me it's a string or character literal type designator prefix.

Comment: @user4581301 It's supposed to come from `<linux/types.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

`u8` isn't in the standard but `uint8_t` is (included in `stdint.h` and `cstdint`). Check your includes, verify that you defined `u8` somewhere.

Comment: Nitpick: In modern code you should `#include <cstdint>` rather than `stdint.h`.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Good precision

Comment: `u8` is not in the standard, but it is expected to be defined in `<linux/types.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the `<linux/types.h>` kernel header, and I can't find `u8`. There is a `__u8` pulled in via `<asm/types.h>`, through two more layers of inclusion.

If I compile

```
#include <linux/types.h>
u8 u;
```

on Ubuntu 18 with gcc-7.3.0, it suggests this.

```
test.c:2:1: error: unknown type name ‘u8’; did you mean ‘__u8’?
u8 u;
^~
__u8
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed all the sentences u [8,16,32] to __u [8,16,32]. Beyond the notation does not involve any change ?. The original code is from a Gumstix of the year 2008. Will it only be due to changes in Linuux during the time?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to bring these datatypes into your program instead of using the standard C ones like `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`.